# How do I load keyboard backlight at boot?

Tags: boot, command-line, keyboard, backlight

I would like to turn on my keyboard backlight at boot so I don't have to manually with terminal at each boot.

The code that works for me in terminal is "sudo xset led 3". Without quotes.

I tried using the startup applications and added a new startup program named Keyboard Backlight and I put the command "sudo xset led 3" but was not successful because it didnt load at boot, what did I do wrong? I think I might have to create a .bin file and locate it?

If there is a easier solution like downloading another program that can load commands at boot that are not .bin files please tell me about it!!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625650/143980) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Create or open and append script `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add your command without sudo, as it will run at startup as root.

```
#!/bin/sh    
/usr/bin/xset led 3
```

Save, reboot and have fun

Comment: It didn't work for me. I followed everything you said and made the file, pasted the commands and saved it. I also double checked to make sure it saved by going to etc and double clicking rc.local file and yes it is saved.                                                                           I rebooted and the keyboard backlight flickered for a second and stayed off. I still had to manually turn it on with terminal. :(

Comment: @Jason [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625650/143980) is a more generic approach that lets you either set keyboard backlight to be **continuously** `on` since boot time or to be `on` since boot time **only during an specific time interval** (e.g. 6 PM till 8 AM).