# Keyboard backlight at login screen

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-backlight

So I have a keyboard with a LED backlight.  I can enable to backlight with

`xset led 3`

I placed it in the .bashrc file and *after* I login, the backlight enables.  Great.  However, it would be nice to have it enabled at the login screen.  I saw this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109242/how-do-i-load-keyboard-backlight-at-boot) on AskUbuntu, but it didnt work for the OP or for me.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625650/143980) help you?